# Active Storage and Multi Tenancy giving error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an application where I use multi tenancy and also active storage. However I have a problem when trying to retrieve the image URL. It seems that everything is correctly inserted in the base of the specific company, but when trying to view the image, this error occurs to me:

[image: print error]

Below are images of the record in the C1 schema database

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I even created a separate app without tenancy to test active storage and it worked, only on that application that I'm using tenancy that doesn't work.

```
  # GET /api/v1/products/:id
  def show
    if @product.image.attached? 
      render json: url_for(@product.image), status: :ok
    end
  end
```

using postman, add browser http://localhost.... but not found.

[image]

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :package

  has_one_attached :image

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

this is params in controller

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:id, :name, :sequence, :address, :ean, :package_id,
    :integration_id, :image)
end
```

this log
[image]

Comment: Please provide some code, how you add the image and the way you want to get the image url. Are you using a background worker or job?

Comment: Hi @Archer I incremented my question.

Comment: Mhh I cannot see any problem. How fast you want to get the url after upload?

Comment: As well? I just want to fetch the image from the bank after uploading it. In this case, the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Rails using jobs to analyze the image. There are some cases, the image should be present, but the job isn't completed yet. You should request the image, when the upload was committed.

It should work, when the upload method returns the url.

Maybe you need to reload the Model before returning it.

```rb
url_for(@product.image.reload)
```